# Debugging a code to print the wordcount: type error: Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, dictionary, debugging, word-count

Here, I want to print a word cloud. I have a different solution that works, but I would like to know what is the error in mine. Could someone check this out? I'm getting a type error: Image data cannot be converted to float.

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
    
    new_list= ""
    new_list2= ""
    my_dict= {}

    
    file_contents1=file_contents.split()
    for letters in file_contents:
        if letters.isalpha():
            letters+=new_list2

    
    
    for letters in new_list2:
        if letters not in uninteresting_words or  letters not in punctuations:
            letters+=new_list
    
    file_content = new_list.lower()
    for word in file_content:
        if word in my_dict:
            my_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            my_dict[word] = 1
    return my_dict
    print(new_list2)

    
            
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(my_dict)
    return cloud.to_array()

myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, this Python3 wordcloud is the last assessment of the first certificate Crash Course on Python, part of Google IT Automation with Python Professional Certificate on coursera and I passed it. Second, if you really developed different code it should be very easy for you to develop another one. But for the sake of mutual help, the mistake is: You are not correctly generating a dictionary from the file_contents. Do some reps on generating dictionary with word_count_frequency function of any random text. Focus on that part, the rest is very easy to implement. Good Luck.

Comment: The excise is a very common python one and can be easily found on the web.I checked that out, will try at it again.

Comment: No problem. You just need to practice generating dictionary with word_count_frequency function. It is the skeleton of what you are searching for.